# Inverse list without losing references

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In an interview question, I saw this. How inverse the content of this list without loose the references.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {"AA", "BB", "CC" };
```

Update:

The question is more like this, you have:

```
public void ReversedList<T>(IList<T> listToReverse)
{
 // To be implemented
}
```

sample the list has 1,2,3,4 and must return 4,3,2,1 without lose reference.

Comment: If some asked me this in an interview I would ask if it is some trick question. This is trivial stuff that has no place in an interview, it is more appropriate for the screening process.

Comment: You can do the old swapping algorithm - replace 1st with last, second with one before last etc...

Comment: Are you sure about the std::List or was it more like C linked list structure?

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean *reverse*, i.e. change the order to "CC", "BB", "AA"? Just call [`List<T>.Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx):

```
list.Reverse();
```

If that's not what you mean, please edit your question to be more specific. (It's not really clear what you mean by "without loose the references" either.)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, `list.Reverse()` would do exactly what you want (reverse the elements in place rather than create a new list with identical items in the reverse order).